# How to make a matrix of radio buttons?

Tags: sapui5

I have to make a matrix of radio buttons exactly like the image attached (this is from https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/radio-button/). But only one option selected per line.
[image: matrix radio buttons]

Since the image is from the guidelines shouldn't we be able to reproduce it easily? Been trying to work with radio button groups but it doesn't end up looking like this...

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look on https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.m.RadioButtonGroup/sample/sap.m.sample.RadioButtonGroup

You can just create 2 groups and align them. With a bit of predefined css classes i think you would get your result. Or you use `groupName` but you cant use it with RadioButtonGroup.

Radiogroup with a bit of adjustment from your side:

```
  <FlexBox class="sapUiMediumMarginBeginEnd">
      <Label text="Foo" class="sapUiLargeMarginBeginEnd"/>
      <Label text="Bar" class="sapUiLargeMarginBegin"/>
    </FlexBox>
        <HBox class="sapUiTinyMarginTopBottom">
       <Label text="selected"/>
    <RadioButtonGroup id="rbg3" columns="5" valueState="Error" class="sapUiMediumMarginBottom">
            <RadioButton id="RB3-1" text="Option 1" />
            <RadioButton id="RB3-2" text="Option 2" />
            <RadioButton id="RB3-3" text="Option 3" />
        </RadioButtonGroup>
        </HBox>
        <HBox class="sapUiTinyMarginTopBottom">
       <Label text="unselected"/>
    <RadioButtonGroup id="rbg4" columns="5" valueState="Error" class="sapUiMediumMarginBottom">
            <RadioButton id="RB3-5" text="Option 1" />
            <RadioButton id="RB3-6" text="Option 2" />
            <RadioButton id="RB3-7" text="Option 3" />
        </RadioButtonGroup>
    </HBox>
    </VBox>
```

or you can do this with the `groupName`which i would prefere more, but here also a little adjustment with the flexbox.

```
<VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
    <HBox class="sapUiTinyMarginTopBottom">
    <FlexBox class="sapUiMediumMargin" direction="Column" alignItems="Start">
            <Label text="Selected" />
            <Label text="Unselected" class="sapUiTinyMarginTop"/>
        </FlexBox>
        <VBox class="sapUiMediumMarginEnd">
            <Label text="Success" labelFor="groupB" />
                <RadioButton text="Option 1" groupName="test1" />
                <RadioButton text="Option 2" groupName="test2" />
        </VBox>
        <VBox class="sapUiMediumMarginEnd">
            <Label text="Error" labelFor="groupC" />
                <RadioButton text="Option 1" groupName="test1" />
                <RadioButton text="Option 2" groupName="test2" />
        </VBox>
        <VBox class="sapUiMediumMarginEnd">
            <Label text="Warning" labelFor="groupD" />
                <RadioButton text="Option 1" groupName="test1" />
                <RadioButton text="Option 2" groupName="test2" />
        </VBox>
        <VBox class="sapUiMediumMarginEnd">
            <Label text="Information" labelFor="groupE" />
                <RadioButton text="Option 1" groupName="test1" />
                <RadioButton text="Option 2" groupName="test2" />
        </VBox>
    </HBox>
</VBox>
```

Comment: It is not the same example. I need to be able to select only one option per line and also have the labels.

Comment: yeah sorry my bad didnt read the "but only one option selected per line"

Comment: i adjust my comment maybe this helps you.

Comment: If you take out the text properties from the radiobuttons then it looks almost the same as my example. The only thing missing would be the alignment of the "Unselected" Label... It's not aligned with the radio buttons.

Comment: @BlueHeart did you try the second example? as is told the first one you had to play around with it .. the second should be fine when you delete the Text attribute in the Radiobuttons

Comment: I did try the second one and the labels aren't aligned.

Comment: @BlueHeart hmm looks for me ok -> https://plnkr.co/edit/MRHNbSZxvIAKoVms

Comment: In order to align everything perfectly it needs more work but I'll still consider it a valid answer. With a sap.m.Table gives less trouble and is more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the "groupName" Property?

```
Name of the radio button group the current radio button belongs to. You can define a new name for the group. If no new name is specified, this radio button belongs to the sapMRbDefaultGroup per default. Default behavior of a radio button in a group is that when one of the radio buttons in a group is selected, all others are unselected.
```

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.RadioButton%23controlProperties

Comment: Yes I did but I'm using the RaddioButtonGroup wrapper so it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just using a sap.m.Table and for the content used sap.m.Text and sap.m.RadioButton. Also important to use groupName to distinguish the two radio button lines.
`

```
<mvc:View
 controllerName="HelloWorld.App"
 xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
 xmlns="sap.m">
 <Page title="My App"/>
    <Table id="idProductsTable">
        <columns>
            <Column>
                <Text 
                text="" />
            </Column>
            <Column
                hAlign="Center">
                <Text text="Low"/>
            </Column>
            <Column
                hAlign="Center">
                <Text text="Medium" />
            </Column>
            <Column
                hAlign="Center">
                <Text text="High" />
            </Column>
        </columns>
        <items>
            <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle">
                <cells>
                    <Text
                        text="First Line" />
                    <RadioButton
                        groupName="1"/>
                    <RadioButton
                        groupName="1"/>
                    <RadioButton
                        groupName="1"/>
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
            <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle">
                <cells>
                    <Text
                        text="Second Line" />
                    <RadioButton 
                        groupName="2"/>
                    <RadioButton
                        groupName="2"/>
                    <RadioButton
                        groupName="2"/>
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
    </Table>
</mvc:View>
```

`